# Sublime Text 2. Shortcut for navigation over blocks of text like Vim shift + [

Tags: vim, sublimetext2, keyboard-shortcuts

I have blocks of text(or functions/methods), which are separated by one or two empty lines. I want to jump over this blocks.

Does Sublime text 2 have this feature?

*ps:
In Vim I can use it with shift + [ or ].*

Comment: Did you try vintage mode? That's `{` and `}` by the way.

Comment: Yes, it works, but it requires switching to command mode. 2 extra motions. I've tried to copy key binding "shift+}" from vintage keymap,but to my surprise haven't found it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, vintage mode is only option for my needs.